# Dashboard to Powerpoint in TABLEAU Public

Tags: tableau-api

I am using TABLEAU Public.. I am not using TABLEAU Desktop.

I created a Dashboard and stored in TABLEAU Public .

Now I want to have the dashboard which I created in terms of Power point presentation.

Is it possible in TABLEAU public  to convert dashboard in to Power point(.ppt)?

Comment: There's a powerpoint addon for live web pages. You could use this to place tableau public content in a power point. http://skp.mvps.org/liveweb.htm otherwise, can't you just screen shot it and place it into a powerpoint?

Comment: Ok. got it . I was looking for any export option in the TABLEAU public design sheet itself.. is there any way like File-->export-->ppt?

Comment: If there is a way to convert our worksheet to PDF using TABLEAU public design tool, then Could you please share that ?

Comment: Sorry, not on Public.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is option to download your worksheet in pdf,image but you dashboard will not integrative or dynamic.

[image]

I recommand you to put link and display in web.